# C++ Application not running on windows docker container as it is dependant on opencv binaries (OPENCV_CORE249DLL & opencv_highgui249.dll)

Tags: c++, opencv, docker, docker-container

My C++ application is not running as it is dependant on opencv binaries (OPENCV_CORE249DLL & opencv_highgui249.dll)

Comment: what kind of docker container are you trying to run this in? is it running windowsservercore? did you install opencv inside the container?

Comment: Yes it is windowsservercore, no I havent installed opencv. If I need to install opencv, then what i need to do, please help.